# SQL: How to create two fields based on same field from another table?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am sure this is quite easy to find, but through my searching I have been unable to find a solution. I'm probably not looking for the right keywords, so hopefully someone can help me.

I have two tables and I am trying to run a select query that will create two new fields based on the same field from another table.

Example: 
`Table1` contains two fields called `AgencyCountryCode` and `ClientCountryCode` so I need to create two new fields called `AgencyCountryName` and `ClientCountryName`. In `Table2` I have a list of country codes and country names to match with.

I have used the below code to match the agency country code to the name, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing for client, using the same lookup table/field.

```
SELECT
...various other fields...
CountryList.[CountryName] AS AgencyCountryName, 
FROM BookingData 
INNER JOIN CountryList ON BookingData.[Agency Country Code] = CountryList.[CountryCode];
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can perform the same lookup on two different fields?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another `JOIN`:

```
SELECT     ...various other fields...
           ACL.[CountryName] AS AgencyCountryName, 
           CCL.[CountryName] AS ClientCountryName
FROM       BookingData BD
INNER JOIN CountryList ACL ON BD.[Agency Country Code] = ACL.[CountryCode]
INNER JOIN CountryList CCL ON BD.[Client Country Code] = CCL.[CountryCode]
```

Comment: That's perfect. I did try to run two inner joins, but slightly different to how you suggested. Thanks