# How to SELECT one column twice, but with different JOINS?

Tags: mysql

I have two FOREIGN KEYS('visitante' and 'visitada') connected to a single ID.

What I have is this:

```
[Print screen of code][1]
```

Typed code:

```
SELECT j.id_jogo, j.data, j.hora, j.resultado_visitada,
j.resultado_visitante, j.local,
t_equipas.nome as 'visitada', t_equipas.nome as 'visitante' FROM t_jogos as j
LEFT JOIN t_equipas
   ON t_equipas.id_equipa = j.id_equipa_visitante
   WHERE j.id_modalidade = 1;
```

With this, logically, it displays only the values of 'visitante' something like this:

```
| visitada  | visitante |
     x            x
     y            y
     z            z
```

I can do a LEFT JOIN for the 'visitante', but I don't know how to do it both in one query.

EDIT: Found the solution here: [SQL: How to create two fields based on same field from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169610/sql-how-to-create-two-fields-based-on-same-field-from-another-table)

FINAL CODE:

```
SELECT j.id_jogo, j.id_equipa_visitante, j.id_equipa_visitada, j.data,
j.hora, j.resultado_visitada,
j.resultado_visitante, j.local,
eqA.nome as 'visitante', eqB.nome as 'visitada' FROM t_jogos as j
LEFT JOIN t_equipas eqA ON eqA.id_equipa = j.id_equipa_visitante
LEFT JOIN t_equipas eqB ON eqB.id_equipa = j.id_equipa_visitada
WHERE j.id_modalidade = 1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I dont really fully understand the question but are you looking for a normal join? or possibly a full outer join

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired output

Comment: A friend found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169610/sql-how-to-create-two-fields-based-on-same-field-from-another-table

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple join conditions, You can add as many joins as you want like this -

```
select * from 
table_a as a inner join table_b as b
on a.A = b.B
inner join table_a as a 
on a.A = a.B
inner join table_b as b 
on a.A = b.A;
-- SO ON joining till n number of tables...
```

Hope this helps. The answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169610/sql-how-to-create-two-fields-based-on-same-field-from-another-table) revolves around this concept.